# How do I create the SwCsharpAddin project in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, solidworks

When I create SwCSharpAddin project, vs2019 reports an error as follows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you post message as text instead of screen capture?

Answer (score 1):

The **SolidWorksToolsWizard.dll** is not registered.

You can find this DLL in the folder after unzipping your "SOLIDWORKS API SDK.msi".

First open you Global Assembly Cache (GAC) under **"%windir%\assembly"** and then just drag-n-drop the DLL into the folder. Then it should automatically be registered in the GAC.